# Seventh Author in apa6

Tags: apa6

I want to have seven authors in the apa6 document class. Unfortunately apa6 only offers up to six authors.

```
\documentclass{apa6}

\title{Title}

\sixauthors{Author 1}{Author 2}{Author 3}{Author 4}{Author 5}{Author 6}
\sixaffiliations{Affiliation 1}{Affiliation 2}{Affiliation 3}{Affiliation 4}{Affiliation 5}{Affiliation 6}

\abstract{Abstract}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Here is what I have:
[image: Six Authors]

Here is what I want:
[image]

I appreciate your help :)